# MYSQL have update query delete if it updates to a duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have 3 different tables that look like this

```
| appearance |    | goal         |    | card         |
|------------|    |--------------|    |--------------|
| id         |    | appearanceID |    | appearanceID |
| playerName |
```

Now the problem is, I was adding data to this table via a script from two difference sources, and so it duplicated some players names with slightly different spelling. I know I can simply run

```
UPDATE appearance
SET playerName = 'xx'
WHERE playername = 'YY';
```

However, that fails because sometimes there was already an entry of player X, and I don't allow duplicate appearances.

Basically I want to be able to write an easy query that says:

"Go change any instance of playerName Y to be X, if it says it already exists then delete the old ones, and also do the same thing for all the appearanceID's that reference player Y."

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

To delete the duplicate rows in `appearance`, you could do this:

```
DELETE a1 FROM appearance a1
INNER JOIN appearance a2
WHERE
    a1.playerName = a2.playerName
    and a1.id > a2.id;
```

This assumes that the older record is the one with a lower `id` and deletes the newer record(s).

You may also wish to introduce some logic to check for duplicates on insert to prevent them from occurring in the first place.